# Как я могу получить "text" в данной функции?

Tags: javascript, node.js

**Я хочу получить "text" например в данной функции:**

```
a = async function(){
'сам текст'.slice(3) 
}
```

```
'Лялял'.a()
```

**и должно получится ял**

Comment: данный код выдает ошибку _Uncaught TypeError: "text".function is not a function_

Comment: я задал вопрос......

Comment: Вы непонятно задали вопрос.

Comment: никак, потому что у строки нет метода `function`.

Comment: Я хочу получить "text" в функции например:
function(){
'сам текст'.slice(3)
}
'Лялял'.function()
и должно получится ял

Comment: вот и приведи в вопросе пример, как ты добавляешь этот метод, тогда можно будет дать ответ.

Comment: Ок,простите за мою неправильную формулировку

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы функцию можно было вызвать в виде

```
"string literal".fun(...);
```

Ее нужно добавить в [`String.prototype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/prototype)

Так как теперь функция стала методом самой строки, то для обращения к строке можно использовать ключевое слово [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

```js
String.prototype.fun = function() {
  return this.slice(4)
}


console.log('1234567890'.fun());
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо,целый день думал над тем как это сделать,вы мой спаситель :)

Comment: @KristalkillPlay Но стоит вносить изменения в прототип только при крайней необходимости, понимая последствия) В большинстве случаев пример из вашего вопроса прописывают так: `a('Лялял'); function a(str) { console.log(str); }`

Comment: Я знаю,просто так мне будет удобнее

Comment: Если код двух людей, которым так было удобно, запустить вместе -- получится ерунда.

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov, это зависит от конкретного кода, может получится, может нет.